# All possible model validation errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, forms

I have got a form with a bunch of fields and model validations.

How can I return all possible validation errors that can be raised?

I need it to write locales for all of them.

I want to get a list like this:

```
password blank
password too_short
password confirmation
login blank
login invalid
email blank
email too_short
email invalid
```

etc

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Basically what Pablo says, except that the page on the rails docs doesn't show how to override the messages for a particular model and field.  here's an example from one of my apps:

```
activerecord:
  errors:
    full_messages:
      format: "{{message}}"    
    #define standard error messages, which we can overide on per model/per attribute basis further down
    messages:
      inclusion: "{{attribute}} is not included in the list"
      exclusion: "{{attribute}} is reserved"
      invalid: "{{attribute}} is invalid"
      confirmation: "{{attribute}} doesn't match confirmation"
      accepted: "{{attribute}} must be accepted"
      empty: "{{attribute}} can't be empty"
      blank: "{{attribute}} can't be blank"
      too_long: "{{attribute}} is too long (maximum is {{count}} characters)"
      too_short: "{{attribute}} is too short (minimum is {{count}} characters)"
      wrong_length: "{{attribute}} is the wrong length (should be {{count}} characters)"
      taken: "{{attribute}} has already been taken"
      not_a_number: "{{attribute}} is not a number"
      greater_than: "{{attribute}} must be greater than {{count}}"
      greater_than_or_equal_to: "{{attribute}} must be greater than or equal to {{count}}"
      equal_to: "{{attribute}} must be equal to {{count}}"
      less_than: "{{attribute}} must be less than {{count}}"
      less_than_or_equal_to: "{{attribute}} must be less than or equal to {{count}}"
      odd: "{{attribute}} must be odd"
      even: "{{attribute}} must be even"
      record_invalid: "Validation failed: {{errors}}"    
    models:
      quiz:
        blank: "{{attribute}} can not be blank"
      user_session:
        blank: "{{attribute}} can not be blank"
        attributes:
          login:
            invalid: "Please enter your user name"   
          password:
            invalid: "Please note that passwords are case sensitive"
```

I've also changed the basic format for error messages, as sometimes i didn't want the field name shoved at the start of the message.  So, i changed

```
errors:
  format: "{{attribute}} {{message}}"
```

to

```
errors:
  format: "{{message}}"
```

Which is why i then specify `{{attribute}}` in my subsequent errors, to put it back in in most but not all cases.

Note also that i'm using the old syntax of `{{var}}` rather than `%{var}`.  The same principles apply though.

Comment: thanks, I know all this stuff, problem is how to get a list of errors for particular model to rewrite its errors for my model specific messages

Comment: Since each validation usually has one error message, you can use the validators property of a model class to instrocpect wich validations are applied to your model, then use a map between the validation class and its error message.  Another aproach could be replace I18n.translate with I18n.translate! while you are testing, run your tests for each language you need to support, and fix all missing translations by hand.

Comment: @Pablo Castellazz, In my case each validation has different error message :) That is the problem

Comment: You mean, the same validation for different fields has different error messages in the same model?

Answer (score 3):

The latest rails translations are at: [rails-i18n](https://github.com/svenfuchs/rails-i18n/tree/master/rails/locale).

ActiveRecord errors are under *lang*:errors and *lang*:active_record in each .yaml.

Also in your application under config/locales/en.yml is the default.

Comment: That's good :) I like it. But here I want to return all possible error for particular model

Comment: That's tricky. There is the validators propety for each model class which all you to get some basic validation introspection. But a more simple aproach will be to simple create an instance of the model, call validate on it, and check the result of the errors property.

Comment: Something i forgot to ask, why not add the right locale file for your language and change config.i18n.default_locale in config/application.rb to use it?

Comment: I can call `validate` for a blank instance, but I won't get all errors (invalid or confirmation errors won't be raised). And I don't want to use global locale because I want to set individual errors for many models for each error